# How to use a program to do omni-completion for VIM

Tags: vim

I'm looking to create a custom omni completion for VIM, and I want to do the actual work of finding possible matches to be done in another program. What would be the best way to go about this?

My idea so far would be to create a vimscript that sends the entire buffer and the location of the cursor to an external script. However I haven't been able to find a more efficient way of getting the buffer than by using `join(getline(0, line('$')), '\n')`, which is very slow on large files. If you are interested, what I have so far:

AutoComplete vimscript:

```
fun! MyComplete(findstart, base)
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
        let start -= 1
    endwhile
    if a:findstart
        return start
    else
        let result = system('java AutoComplete '.shellescape(expand('%')).' '.line('.').' '.start, 'File sourcecode here')
        let res = []
        for m in split(result)
            if m =~ '^' . a:base
                call add(res, m)
            endif
        endfor
        return res
    endif
endfun
set completefunc=MyComplete
```

AutoComplete.java:

```
class AutoComplete {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        // To be expanded into an amazing program...
        System.out.print("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to create a temporary file and pass its name to an external command. For example, this is from clang_complete plugin:

```
let l:buf = getline(1, '$')
let l:tempfile = expand('%:p:h') . '/' . localtime() . expand('%:t')
try
    call writefile(l:buf, l:tempfile)
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E482/
    " TODO: handle exception
endtry

" TODO: call external program here

call delete(l:tempfile)
```

See also the [QueryCommandComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4132) plugin, which can be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think I might also try something like `silent! exe "write foo.txt"` to write the temp file.